# Is it possible to display and image inside the add-on about?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Text works but a gif sometimes can be more inspiring and explain things visually better.

Any idea if it is possible to display a gif /image inside the shortcuts area?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show custom icons, see: [How to implement custom icons for my script/addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32335/how-to-implement-custom-icons-for-my-script-addon/32336#32336)

However you can't show large images in this space.

Answer (score 3):

Blender does not include support for reading gifs.

[2.75 added](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/Addons) the ability for addons to access image previews and use them as icons in the layout. You can find two example templates within blenders text editor [ui_previews_custom_icon.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_previews_custom_icon.py) and [ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py) showing how to use them.

See: *Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Previews Custom Icon / UI Previews Dynamic Enum*:

[image]