# AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘space_data’

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I am using blender 3.2, am trying to execute the below steps using python script

1. Import Rigged avatar (.glb) into Blender
2. Select the mesh of upper human body
3. Go to shade editor, delete existing material and add new material
4. @shade editor, select "Principled BSDF" and use Hot key ctrl + shift + t to upload the image of texture
   (Node wrangler is already enabled)
5. Adjust the scale parameters at the Mapping node
6. Export the updated avatar in same glb format

I generated the below script for the above steps:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\stage\\STAGEGLB3.glb", files=[{"name":"STAGEGLB3.glb", "name":"STAGEGLB3.glb"}], loglevel=50)
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
bpy.ops.material.new()
bpy.ops.node.select(deselect_all=True, location=(420, 240))
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled(filepath="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\brown_color.jpg", directory="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\", files=[{"name":"brown_color.jpg", "name":"brown_color.jpg"}], relative_path=True)
bpy.data.materials["Material.003"].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].inputs[3].default_value[0] = 5
bpy.data.materials["Material.003"].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].inputs[3].default_value[1] = 5
bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 3
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
bpy.context.space_data.system_bookmarks_active = 1
bpy.context.space_data.params.filename = "STAGEGLB4.glb"
```

The error am getting at line 3 is

**AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘space_data’**

I tried with this link [AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'space_data'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64370/attributeerror-restrictcontext-object-has-no-attribute-space-data)
still no luck

pls suggest the way forward.

Thanks

vij

Comment: Uninitialized context is often because Blender didn't have time to build everything correctly. Try using an application timer to delay your script a little bit (100 ms should be enough) https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: Thanks @Gorgious for yur timely help, yur timer has helped us... Now the error at line 7   AttributeError: module 'bpy.ops.node' has no attribute 'nw_add_textures_for_principled' 
             can u help us here pls..

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by using timer
Thanks to @Gorgious

Updated code is

```
def sd(message):
         bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="C:\\Users\\STAGEGLB3.glb", files= 
         [{"name":"STAGEGLB3.glb", "name":"STAGEGLB3.glb"}], loglevel=50)

  bpy.context.space_data.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
  bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(sd, "Hello"), first_interval=12.0)
  bpy.ops.material.new()
 bpy.ops.node.select(deselect_all=True, location=(420, 240))
```