# Make an add-on with multiple python files

Tags: python, workflow

I was looking through some add-ons that ship with blender so I could better understand how to use multiple files for an add-on.

I tried running the *add_curve_extra_objects* plugin's **init**.py however when I do I get this error:`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

So how do I specify the parent directory or get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organize your folder structure like this:

```
myaddon/
├── __init__.py
├── operators/
    ├── first_operator.py
```

In the `__init__.py` do this:

```
import bpy

from .operators.first_operator import FirstOperator

bl_info = {
    "name": "MyAddon",
    "description": "A demo addon",
    "author": "myname",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 9),
    "wiki_url": "my github url here",
    "tracker_url": "my github url here/issues",
    "category": "Animation"
}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

In the `operators/first_operator.py` file, do this:

```
import bpy

class FirstOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "First Operator"
    bl_idname = "myaddon.first_operator"
    bl_description = "A demo operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("hello world")

        return {"FINISHED"}
```

You'll have to install the addon to use it. You can't just run the `__init__.py` from the text editor in Blender to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps also explain that the chosen `myaddon` name is where you can import using absolute imports.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the installed add on if I changed something to it?

Comment: Try the "Refresh" button in the user preferences window. I typically just restart Blender when I'm working on an addon.

Comment: is this still the same as of 2.8+ right now?

Comment: this doesnot work for 2.92