# Use new Icons in custom interface

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to use new UI icons in some addons, But actually I get all the Old ones

[image]

change the Icons is easy, but this get the Old one

```
row.operator("view3d.nn", text="Sculpt", icon = "BRUSH_INFLATE")
```

I thought I was missing something, then I call the template_ID_preview, but this return the Old icon too.

```
paint = context.tool_settings.sculpt
layout.template_ID_preview(paint, "brush", rows=3, cols=8, hide_buttons=True)
```

**** update*

Actually I use the `icon_value` from 0 to 5000 but the result is the same old UI icons

```
        row = layout.row()

        icons = bpy.types.UILayout.bl_rna.functions["prop"].parameters["icon"].enum_items.keys()
        c=0
        while c != 5000:
            print(icons[c])
            c+=1

            
            row.label(text= str(c), icon_value =c)

            if c%10 ==0:
                row = layout.row()
                row = row.row(align=True)
```

[image: old fashion UI icons]
what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean the colored versions with the blue bits in the tool panel?  If so, those are custom icons and you have to use `icon_value =` and find their icon id value, rather than `icon =` in the call to `row.operator`

Comment: @MartyFouts actually I test the icon_value from 0 to 5000 and the result is the same old icons....  the maximum icon_value with some result is 818.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the custom brush icons, you need to import and use an undocumented helper class.  Here's an example that puts a pane in the object data properties using the 'draw' icon:

```
import bpy
from bl_ui.space_toolsystem_common import ToolSelectPanelHelper

class PreviewsExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Previews Example Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        #pcoll = icons_dict["draw"]
        row = layout.row()
        #my_icon = pcoll["draw"]
        #row.operator("render.render", text="", icon_value=my_icon.icon_id)
        icon_id = ToolSelectPanelHelper._icon_value_from_icon_handle('brush.sculpt.draw')
        row.operator("render.render", text="", icon_value=icon_id)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

That produces:

[image: Previews Example Panel]

You can find all of the custom tool icons using this code, adapted from [How to get toolbar icons names](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-get-toolbar-icons-names/6541) on devtalk

```py
icons = []

cls = ToolSelectPanelHelper._tool_class_from_space_type('VIEW_3D')
for item_group in cls.tools_from_context(bpy.context):
    if type(item_group) is tuple:
        index_current = cls._tool_group_active.get(item_group[0].idname, 0)
        for sub_item in item_group:
            print(sub_item.label)
            icons.append(sub_item.icon)
    else:
        if item_group is not None:
            print(item_group.label)
            icons.append(item_group.icon)
```