# How does blender make native icons with different colors?

Tags: interface, add-on, customization

I'm making an addon for blender and I want to change the color of the native icons used in the custom layout for a better visual experience.

I made this simple grid to display all possible icons, but as it turns out the icons are in black and white, instead of having the expected colors like shown below:

[image: a grid list containing all Blender's built-in icons]

I would like to know how I can make my icons have colors, and also how to customize their color if possible.

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Interface/Icons

Comment: Those are not colored. They are given color by the theme's settings. This is not exposed to Python API in any way. You have to make custom icons if you want them to be different. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32335/how-to-implement-custom-icons-for-my-script-addon